# Setting up a virtual host on LAMP (Ubuntu 11) returns 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lamp, virtualhost

i am having problems with setting up a virtual host (Aptana Project directory) on a **LAMP** installation on **Ubuntu 11** (via tasksel).

i can access 
/var/www via ht*p://localhost, but accessing `/home/tg/Aptana..`. via `ht*p://ea-dev` returns an

> "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

this is my apache2.conf: http://pastebin.com/Yja02tnE
this is my ea-dev located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/: http://pastebin.com/U1Vu2jxD

thats what i get in the error.log:

> [crit] [client 127.0.0.1]
>   (13)Permission denied: /home/tg/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to
>   check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

I really don't understand why its written `/home/tg` and not `/home/tg/Aptana..`. but maybe its just an abbreviation.

Comment: and this is my default located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/: http://pastebin.com/Ayv9dPRk

Comment: oh and btw, thats what appears when i try to restart apache:

Comment: * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                                              apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Fri Jun 03 15:58:19 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure the user running the apache daemon can read the files in the directories in question? I'd start with the .htaccess file. That is almost always the cause of the permission denied error. You may also need to add the tg user to the www-data group.

However, the other thing that stands out is the use of spaces in your path for DocumentRoot... I haven't actually ever done that, so I would also try normalizing your directory path, removing spaces and capital letters. That could explain why the path in the error log does not match the path you expected to see - apache does not normally abbreviate such things.

Good luck and let us know if you make any progress or have additional questions/info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The spaces were not the problems, but the permissions were inappropriately set, as you suggested in the first place. I ran the commands: `sudo chmod o+rx '/home'
sudo chmod o+rx '/home/tg'
sudo chmod o+rx '/home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace'
sudo chmod o+rx '/home/tg/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ea-dev'`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I guess it could not report the full path in the error log due to the same permissions issue. Good to know about the spaces.